# Nougat downloaded but now not in notifications

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I got an over the air nougat update on my Nexus 5x phone. I downloaded it but hadn't installed it yet. Now I don't see the notification on the phone. How can I get it back so I can click to install it?  Note I already tried check for updates but no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to sideload it I believe you will get it with the next OTA wave. Also, I remember people were forcing OTA with Google Service Framework disabled back when 5.0 came out, but I havent tried it so I really don't know if that works or not. Here are the steps if you want to give it a try:

1. Find Google Service Framework in the Apps section of your Settings menu
2. Force stop it.
3. Try the System Update option now.

Comment: Thanks I'll wait for it. I am currently on marshmallow and Google service fwk is not an app I see in the app list.